# activiti:skipExpression doesn't work

Tags: java, activiti, bpmn

Today it took me some time to find out how to use the skipExpression feature of Activiti. I wished I had found a question like this, that's why I'll put it here and answer it myself.

I tried using an activiti:skipExpression in a UserTask like this:

```
<userTask id="usertask1" name="Order Book" activiti:assignee="myTestUser1" 
  activiti:skipExpression="${skip == 1}">
</userTask>
```

According to https://activiti.atlassian.net/browse/ACT-2176, this is supposed to be possible since 5.18. But I can't make it work.

I expect that task to be skipped and the following task to be created, but the flow behaves as if the skip expression weren't there (task 1 is created, task 2 isn't created).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From searching Activiti's source code resp. its tests, I found that I have to add an extra variable to each process instance that wants to make use of the skip feature:

```
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("_ACTIVITI_SKIP_EXPRESSION_ENABLED", true);
    params.put("skip", 1);
```

Additionally, the tests writes the expression in the process XML's userTask like this:

```
activiti:skipExpression="${execution.getVariable('skip') == 1}"
```

That param is undocumented in [the Activiti User Guide](http://www.activiti.org/userguide/index.html) of version 5.19 (I'm using 6.0.0.beta1), and there is no word about it in the ticket either, that I mentioned in the question.

Comment: The behavior appears to be the same in 5.18 and yes, the super secret _ACTIVITI_SKIP_EXPRESSION_ENABLED flag must be set to true in the process execution context.

Comment: This behaviour is also observed in flowable v6.7.2 (Originally a fork of activiti) and hence the _ACTIVITI_SKIP_EXPRESSION_ENABLED variable needs to be set there as well.